# How to sum up the values of each category in a series object?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have this DataFrame:

[image: Backpacking equipment DataFrame]

What I need to do is to group the DataFrame by the `Category` column, and then use a function to compute the total weight by each category. This is what I've done so far...

```
def multiply(group, quantity, weight):
  x = group[quantity]
  y = group[weight]

  return x * y

print(df.groupby('Category').apply(multiply, 'Quantity',  'Weight (oz.)'))
```

The result I get is

[image: Quantity by weight]

Now, how do I sum up the total weight by each category (*i.e.*, Pack, Shelter, Sleep, etc.) of the resultant `Series` object?

Comment: Can you paste your dataframe in text format please?

Answer (score 1):

Using a sample of your data:

```
Item,Category,Quantity,Weight (oz.)
Sleeping Pad,Sleep,1,80.0
Sleeping Bag,Sleep,1,20.0
Spoon,Kitchen,1,0.87
Stove,Kitchen,1,20.0
Water Filter,Kitchen,1,1.8
Water Bottles,Kitchen,2,35.0

In [1]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=0)


In [2]: df.groupby('Category').apply(lambda x: (x['Quantity'] *x['Weight (oz.)']).sum())
Out[2]: 
Category
Kitchen     92.67
Sleep      100.00
dtype: float64
```